# Testing attribute_changed? VS. previous_changes in checking if a specific attribute changed (Rails), behaves differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apart from the return type specified by the docs, I was testing the difference between the 2 following lines in 2 different methods in after_save :

`[:attribute_1, :attribute_2].any? {|a| self.send("#{a}_changed?")}`

`[:attribute_1, :attribute_2].any? {|attribute| self.previous_changes.key? attribute.to_s}`

model.save! is called several times, but to my surprise, the first line returned `true` when one of the attributes was changed, but the second returned `false` and previous_changes is an empty hash. Could someone explain why this might happen?

Rails Version: '3.2.22.1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previous changes are prefilled after the model has been saved (and `after_save` callback is part of this process)

If you want the same behaviour, you're probably looking for [changes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) method. Using it will return the results you're expecting.

According to the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes) documentation (it has the same behaviour in Rails 3)

```
person = Person.new
person.name = 'Bob'
person.name_changed?  # => true
person.changes        # => {"name" => [nil, "Bill"]}
person.save

person.name_changed?     # => false
person.changes           # => {}
person.previous_changes  # => {"name" => [nil, "Bill"]}
person.reload!
person.previous_changes  # => {}
```

But if you try to check the same in the `after_commit` callback, then you get the different results, since `after_commit` is called after the model is saved. Thus, `previous_changes` will be prefilled, but `changes` will be empty.